# Can a Turing Machine have fewer states?

Tags: turing-machines

I am currently learning about Turing Machines, I am curious if a Turing Machine can have fewer states ?  Can it be done like a Transition Graph where you can have multiple states at once ?

I got this TM off of a youtube video sorry for bad hand writing, but could I just merge some of the states like you would do in Transition Graph, so instead of having 5 states it would have 4 states ? TM are more advanced so I don't know if you are even able to do this...thanks!

[image]

how could I make this into 4 states TM instead of 5 states ? in TG if would take 5 seconds do it...

Comment: Have fewer states than what? If two states are identical, they can be merged; if they're not, they can't. There's always going to be a point where no more states can be merged: if that wasn't the case, every Turing machine would have only one state, and there aren't many different one-state machines!

Comment: Maybe two related results: (1) there is a universal TM with 2 states and $|\Gamma|=3$. (2) It is undecidable to test if the size of the code of a TM is minimal

Answer (score 1):

It is undecidable to check whether a turing maching has a smaller encoding than a given one.  Hence there cannot be any such concept as a transition graph.

If you simply want a smaller turing maching for your example, I would guess no, from a quick glance of it.

Answer (score 0):

The language of your Turing Machine is : $ \{ a^nb^n | n > 0 \}$.
What about this?
[image]

I think language of this Turing Machine is : $ \{ a^nb^n | n > 0 \}$ but with 
the condition of $A,B \notin \Sigma$.

Comment: And why do you think so?